# Multiple Channel Entries on Template - Works for Home Page - Not for Other Pages

Tags: channel-entries, templates, channel

I rarely do any crazy cross/channel templates. Most EE sites I've developed are based on individual channels. I did something that seems to be working for the home page, but not for the interior pages; e.g., anything past index.php/template-name/page-name

Here's my main template code:

```
{embed="inc/.header.doc-open"}      

    {embed="inc/.left-sidebar"} 

    <div class="ctnr cf two-four grid">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="content" limit="1"}
        <div class="ctnr cf one-one content" id="hero">

            {content_body}

        </div><!-- end #hero -->
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div><!-- end .ctnr -->

    {embed="inc/.right-sidebar"}    

    {embed="inc/.footer.doc-close"}
```

I'm opening/closing channels within each include group; e.g.:

```
        <div class="left-sidebar ctnr cf one-four grid">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="left"}
        {left_content}
    {/exp:channel:entries}  
    </div><!-- end .ctnr -->
```

This seems to be working perfectly on the home page... It sorta works if I just do the following url structure index.php/template-name - This pulls in the most recent entry. Once I put in the actual url title; e.g., index.php/template-name/page-title it pulls the content, but all the includes are messed up. They're getting pulled in, but the content and images aren't.

Any pointers on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding dynamic="no" as a parameter for your channel entries? Since there is no url title on the homepage the entries loops assume it will be a listing, but as soon as you add more segments to your url. The entries try and pull that title. By adding dynamic="no", you are saying that you do not care what the url title is, you just want the listing. Check out the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic)